# How can I add a QComboBox to the Main Toolbar in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I am writing a Text Editor on Qt Creator. I have a QPlainTextEdit as the central widget, and I want all the font-controlling tools in the main toolbar automatically added to all QMainWindow projects. When I try to drag and drop a QComboBox on to the main toolbar, A not-allowed icon is displayed. 
Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do what you want by calling the [`addWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtoolbar.html#addWidget) function of the `QToolBar`. So if you have called your main tool bar `mainToolBar` you can do in the constructor of your main window:

```
QComboBox* myComboBox = new QComboBox;
// Add values in the combo box
ui->mainToolBar->addWidget(myComboBox);
// make the connection between the combo box and a slot
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, looking a bit around in the cpp file I realized that I'm referring the wrong thing.

`ui->mainToolBar->insertWidget(ui->actionLoadSettings, cbxSelect);` will do the trick.